# how to publish sonar result in jenkins server, or do we have sonar-report jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

There is a [sonar plugin for jenkins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Jenkins+Plugin), it triggers the sonar build inside CI (jenkins), it is useful.

While now I want to see the sonar result inside jenkins without jumping to sonar websites, it is useful if I just want to see some key data for this job.

It could be sonar-report plugin in jenkins.

Do you have similar needs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One ugly solution I used so far is to use [Sonar Web API.](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+Service+API)

I add one `curl` command in the end of job (build steps) to fetch the needed metrics like

```
curl http://sonar.sh.cn.ao.ericsson.se//api/resources?metrics=qi-quality-index,coverage,test_success_density&resource=54936 --output sonar-result.xml
```

Then I archive the `sonar-result.xml` to make it visible inside the job.

Comment: Hey Larry, just curious if you've found anything new in regard to this, as I'm about to implement something similar.  Cheers!

Comment: no, not checked further, leave your solution if you can do more

Comment: You can actually parse the json in the jenkins shell with jq, and get the status. So you don't need to save the result in a file etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Mashup Portlets plugin for Jenkins to configure the results in Jenkins Dashboard.

PFB URL for the plugin.

URL:- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mashup+Portlets