# Is it possible to show Fortify scan result on Jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins, fortify

Is there a way to display Fortify scan result on Jenkins?

I've seen only Jenkins plugin to run Fortify scanning and upload result to Fortify server but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortify has a plugin for Jenkins. It allows you to automatically upload results to Software Security Center after a build. The Jenkins plugin also integrates with Software Security Center to show the results of a scan in Jenkins. In your Fortify documentation set, look for a document called HP_Fortify_Jenkins_Plugin_TN_4.30.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I just found that on Google, you can import the Fortify results into a SonarCube instance:
http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/integration/fortify/

And next, you can use the Sonar Web API to publish the results in Jenkins:
[how to publish sonar result in jenkins server, or do we have sonar-report jenkins plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873759/how-to-publish-sonar-result-in-jenkins-server-or-do-we-have-sonar-report-jenkin)

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either Fortify Audit Workbench (AWB) or the Fortify Software Security Center (SSC) to review (aka audit) the issues (FPR file) generated in the Fortify sourceanalyzer.exe step in your Jenkins script. As an open source build and deployment tool, I do not see how Jenkins would be a suitable tool for auditing issues and posting bug reports.  Please clarify your question to explain what you want to with the FPR file on the Jenkins server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you need to invoke an external script (gradle?) and use FPRUtility command with "-query" parameter. You can test the queries using the "Advanced..." search in the audit workbench. If you do it after merging with the previous result (FPRUtility -merge ...) you can achieve an incremental scan.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is CI/CD tool that help to upload the fortify results directly to the SSC(Software security center) after the build.

Integration of HP Fortify with Jenkins :

Step 1) Install Jenkins plugin on cloud server or you can directly access the cloud Jenkins server(if it is already installed on server).

step 2) Create the folder in Jenkins and configure the properties(making changes in configuration file on left side).

Step 3) Disable upload function in Jenkins (Means you can not provide the SSC link, while configuring the configuration file on left side), so that .FPR file will not uploaded automatically on SSC.
Step 4) Once the batch script or groovy script is successfully build , then you would be able to see the result on Jenkins console.

example:

- Critical= 30
          High= 20
          Medium=10

Let me know if you have any question while integrating Jenkins with fortify -SSC.Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I never used Fortify with Jenkins, but here is another alternative that you use with Jenkins, through a plugin. Read about it here: https://blog.probely.com/how-to-configure-jenkins-to-integrate-security-into-ci-cd-2b340728de56

You scan start a scan from Jenkins both in a freestyle and pipeline project.

Full disclosure: I'm highly affiliated with Probely, I'm the CTO :)