# Analyzing ant project with sonar ant task and jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I am using the sonar ant task jar for sonar analysis so I setup it in the project-properties.xml and create an Ant build step in jenkins. When I build the job, the analysis works fine and I am able to see the results in the sonarqube server, but in jenkins no link to SonarQube is visible.

Do I really need to install the SonarQube plugin for the link to be visible for the job?

Answer (score 1):

See also [how to publish sonar result in jenkins server, or do we have sonar-report jenkins plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873759/how-to-publish-sonar-result-in-jenkins-server-or-do-we-have-sonar-report-jenkin)

Normally you let SonarQube handle the code analysis on it's own and not by the Ant task (in the Jenkins job).

The Jenkins plug-in is there to trigger Sonar, to get latest sources (from the SCM) and run the analysis.

The results, are then made available on Sonar, but the Jenkins project, will provide a link to the results.

**Workaround**

There is (for as far as I know) no way to add a link, to an external generated report. What could be done, is add a simple HTML page, with a link to the Sonar server, to the project. And publish that simple HTML page, with the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to configure it using sonarqube plugin and it works fine. But i want to know is there any way by which we can also display the sonarqube hyperlink when I run using ant job. it seems to show anly when I configure the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Looking into similar plugins I found a plugin which is used to just create normal hyperlinks in the sidebar- Sidebar-Link+Plugin